# exceptions and scheduled jobs

Tags: scheduled-apex, exception, scheduled-job

I know if there is an unhandled exception it will "roll back" any dml operations that occurred during the same transaction. Does this also include scheduled jobs? I'm not sure if scheduling a  job is treated as a dml operation or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Enqueueing any form of Asynchronous Apex, including Schedulable, future, Queueable, and Batch, for execution is rolled back if an unhandled exception takes place.

Only non-transactional Platform Events are not rolled back, because by definition they take place outside the transaction.